# Psychic Warrior Meditant Level Count as Monk Levels?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics

"The meditant gains the Improved Unarmed Strike feat as a bonus feat, and may count his meditant levels as monk levels for purposes of effects and prerequisites."

This piece of text is supposedly an official ruling on the [Meditant](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/psychic-warrior/archetypes/dreamscarred-press/meditant) Psychic Warrior archetype, but I can't seem to find its source anywhere. Is it in a book, or was it made via a forum post? I would like to know so I can A. Show my group the original primary source of this ruling and B. Find out if the rumored ruling that the archetype's Flurry of Strikes ability counts as Flurry of Blows can be dug up within the same source as well.

Comment: @AndreasRönnqvist is half of Dreamscarred Press and can likely answer this question. I tried to research this question on the [Dreamscarred Press forums](http://dreamscarred.com/forum/general-discussion/), but forum searches I ran returned me to the home page. Perhaps a registered user would have better luck?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Andreas is not “half” of Dreamscarred Press at this point. He is one of the two founders, though, as I understand things. I’ve pinged him outside this site, so hopefully we can get one of those rare authoritative RAI answers.

Comment: @KRyan My statement was not intended to slight Dreamscarred Press employees but to amplify Rönnqvist's importance. I apologize for my oversight.

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but I came across it in a web search.  I figured I'd check in with an official book answer, as Ultimate Psionics (which has revised/updated/errata'ed rules for all the Psionics Dreamscarred had released previously) answered this specifically.

Under "Flurry of Strikes (Su)"(pg. 276), it specifically states:

"Flurry of strikes counts as flurry of blows for the purposes of effects and prerequisites."

It is perhaps worthwhile to note that while it "counts" as Flurry of Blows, it doesn't duplicate it.  For example, the levels at which the extra attacks are obtained are different between F.o.Strikes and F.o.Blows. F.o.Strikes also interacts differently with weapons and with natural attacks then F.o.Blows does, etc.

Answer (score 1):

At the very end of the [linked page](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/psychic-warrior/archetypes/dreamscarred-press/meditant) is a copyright notice:

> Psionics Expanded: Advanced Psionics Guide. Copyright 2011, Dreamscarred Press; Authors: Jeremy Smith and Andreas Rönnqvist.

The Meditant archetype is described on page 80 of the book. As far as I can see, the text on linked pfsrd page is the same.

The description of **Flurry of Strikes** doesn't mention **Flurry of Blows** at all, therefore, it doesn't count as such, though it wouldn't be an unreasonable houserule for it to do.

Comment: How does this answer the question?  Does the quoted rule not exist?